# Could git open vim editor at line N whenever we are creating commit?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit, neovim, commit-message

I working in a project where each commit in a branch MUST start with

> Story PRJCT-NAME-42 Task description

And must contain a message like this

> Story PRJCT-NAME-42 Task description
>
> foo bar description

I've created a custom message and stored in `~./gitmessage`. The content of the file is

> Story PRJCT-NAME-42 Task description

It is possible t run `git commit` and have focus in line number three?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG :3
```

This will move the cursor to line #3 whenever a file called `COMMIT_EDITMSG` is opened (which is the name of the temporary file used by git while editing a commit message)

Comment: Sorry for the delay but for some reason this is not working